# store tmuxinator config in project repository

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

Is there a way to store tmuxconfig in project repo instead of  `~/.tmuxinator` directory?
If it possible then how I can start session with this config?

Comment: don't use tmuxinator but how about `ln -s ...` ?

Comment: please, describe your idea. How does it help to store config in repo? Or do your propose to create symbolic time for each repo after `git clone`?